# Second form is not loading properly on Visual Builder?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, constructor

in the first form I have a text box where you can add your name, and then when you click Next window, the second form will pop up saying My name is : Your name . This is great, but how would I be able to change the name of the second form known as OtherForm to my name aswell so that when the second form pops up, on the top left corner my name would appear instead of OtherForm? Here is the code for the first and second form so far.

Main Form code:

```
Public Class MainForm

Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
MyBase.Load

End Sub

Public Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
WindowName.TextChanged




End Sub

Public Sub WindowName_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Public Sub OffButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
OffButton.Click
    Me.Close()


End Sub

Public Sub NextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
NextButton.Click
    OtherForm.NameLabel.Text = WindowName.Text
    OtherForm.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

Second form known as OtherForm

```
Public Class OtherForm

Public Sub CloseButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
CloseButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Public Sub OtherForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
MyBase.Load

End Sub

Public Sub NameLabel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
NameLabel.Click


End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Label1.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
OtherForm.Text = WindowName.Text
```

to set the title of the form.  Or you can set the text to whatever you would like.  I'm not sure if you mean "my name" or the name you entered.

If you do mean "my name" then you can enter that in the form property for "Text" instead of in code as well.